# What makes an object thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate

Hash map can access multiple threads simultaneously, so it is not thread safe.

But in Hibernate, the session factory is thread safe, but how as it can be accessed by multiple threads concurrently and request for sessions?

I am confused about thread safety.

This was the one of the interview questions I faced.

Comment: Much too broad. First of all, you got it backwards. Threads use the SessionFactory, not vice-versa. It's thread-safe because it can be used concurrently by multiple threads. Not because it can use multiple threads.

Comment: @JBNizet That comment can be misread, non-thread safe objects can also be used by multiple threads; that doesn't make them thread-safe. Maybe "It's been developed to be thread-safe ..."?

Comment: org.hibernate.SessionFactory if you speak about it is itself not a HashMap and even not a map. Really not clear that is being asked here.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel OK.  It's thread-safe because it can be used (in a safe, predictible, correct way) concurrently by multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of thread safe is simply that the program state (fields/objects/variables) behaves correctly when multiple simultaneous threads are using a resource. The term can be applied to a section of code, a method, a class, a library, an application, etc. The basic meaning remains the same across these scopes, but what is required to be thread safe can vary widely.

The simplest means of making something thread safe is to only access the state from a single thread. Since the stack, and thus all local variables, are within the scope of a single thread, code that doesn't access object fields (either directly or indirectly) and only accesses local variables, is inherently thread safe.

**Hibernate sessionFactory**

A SessionFactory is usually only built once at startup.is threadsafe so that many threads can access it concurrently and request for sessions and immutable cache of compiled mappings for a single database. A SessionFactory is usually only built once at startup.

**HashMap**

If multiple threads access a hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally to avoid an inconsistent view of the contents. (A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more mappings; merely changing the value associated with a key that an instance already contains is not a structural modification.)